# Ms Access VBA set MouseMove event with WithEvents from Class

Tags: vba, class, ms-access, events

I am trying to dynamically assign events to the MouseMove, MouseUp and MouseDown events of a commandbutton (other control auch as label, textbox, etc. would be ok as well).

I have a class for this purpose, however it is only working for the Click event, but not for the MouseMove, MouseUp or MouseDown events. I don't get any errors, but there is no event raised when I move the mouse over the button. I have tried several approaches, but I only ever got it to work for the Click event. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? Here is my code:

Class Module:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

' Class Module: clsButtonHolder
Public WithEvents ButtonControl As Access.CommandButton
Private x_offset As Integer, y_offset As Integer


Public Function AddControl(ctrl As Access.CommandButton) As Access.CommandButton
    Set ButtonControl = ctrl
    ButtonControl.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    Set AddControl = ButtonControl
End Function

Public Sub ButtonControl_Click()
    Debug.Print "Click triggered"
End Sub

Public Sub ButtonControl_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "MouseDown triggered"
End Sub

Public Sub ButtonControl_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "MouseMove triggered"
End Sub

Public Sub ButtonControl_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "MouseUp triggered"
End Sub
```

Form Module:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Dim ButtonHolders As Collection
Dim holder As clsButtonHolder
   

Private Sub btnInit_Click()

    Dim cmdBtn As Access.CommandButton
    
    Set ButtonHolders = New Collection

    Set holder = New clsButtonHolder
    Set cmdBtn = Me.btnTest
    Set holder.ButtonControl = cmdBtn
    holder.AddControl cmdBtn
    
    ButtonHolders.Add holder

End Sub
```

I tried the above code and was expecting the MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events to be triggered (after btnInit is clicked) when the cursor moves above the control (Me.btnTest), but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I was just missing these three lines inside the class module:

```
ButtonControl.OnMouseMove = "[Event Procedure]"
ButtonControl.OnMouseUp = "[Event Procedure]"
ButtonControl.OnMouseDown = "[Event Procedure]"
```